# Angular 2 - Execute code when closing window

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a chat application using angular 2.

How can i send the finish chat command to the backend when the user closes the window?

My component has a method that calls the backend service to end the chat in the following way

```js
 endChat() {
        this.chatService.endChat(this.chatSessionInfo).subscribe(
            result => this.OnGetMessages(result),
            error => this.OnChatEndError(error)
        );
    }
```

How can i execute that code when closing the window? How can i detect the window close event?

I tried with ngOnDestroy but for some reason the code is not being executed.

In my Component.ts I have.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, ElementRef, ViewChild,OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

export class ChatComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked,OnDestroy  {
```

and finally

```
 ngOnDestroy() { 
    this.endChat();
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you implemented the backend with socket.io?

Comment: No, i am using WebApi 2

Comment: I don't know how you wired up your chat in the background, but I'd suggest using [`SignalR`](http://www.asp.net/signalr) for something like a chat. On disconnect there will be [fired an event](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) on the server. Have a look here for an example: https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNET-Core-Angular2-SignalR-Typescript

Comment: use jquery for that check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event

Comment: @rinukkusu I am using socket.io. Do you have a socket.io specific solution for this?

Comment: @MarcBorni No, I'd go with Günter's answer! BUT if you just need to execute some code on your backend, then there is the [`'disconnect'` event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287330/socket-io-handling-disconnect-event).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I was able to create a solution based on different proposal.

First I used the beforeunload event in the component

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    this.endChat();
}
```

where

```
endChat() {
    this.chatService.endChatSync(this.chatSessionInfo);
}
```

Then, the trick is to make the http call sync not async.

Before, the endchat method at the chat service was

```
    endChat(chatSessionInfo: ChatSessionInfo)  : Observable<ChatTranscription> {
    console.log("Ending chat..");
    let body = JSON.stringify(chatSessionInfo);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.delete(this.apiUrl + "Chat?userId="+chatSessionInfo.UserId+"&secureKey="+chatSessionInfo.SecureKey,options)
             .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I was able to make it work with

```
endChatSync(chatSessionInfo: ChatSessionInfo)  {
    console.log("Ending chat..");
     let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
     xhr.open("DELETE",this.apiUrl +"Chat?userId="+chatSessionInfo.UserId+"&secureKey="+chatSessionInfo.SecureKey,false);
     xhr.send();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tested `new XMLHttpRequest()` in all browsers?

Answer (score 23):

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event) {
  ...
}
```

See also [javascript to check when the browser window is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805463/javascript-to-check-when-the-browser-window-is-close)

Comment: Does this have a timeout or does it block until the handler finishes?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload, https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload. I haven't used them myself for a while and don't remember details.

Comment: The issue in that case is that the window get closed before the service call is sent..

Comment: I know thos is tricky but there is nothing Angular can do about it. That's a browser limitation.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Where should i have to write this code?

Comment: `@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])` didn't work for me (Angular2 v2.4.6) to show the confirmation dialog by setting the `e.returnValue`. What did was `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])`, however.

Comment: Take a look at my previous post. That works for Angular 2

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266974/how-to-call-the-api-before-closing-the-browser-window-in-angular4

Comment: I used unloadHandler and beforeUnloadHandler.. sometimes it does logging and sometimes it misses it.. I need log everytime when app is closed...

Answer (score 3):

Chrome now disallows synchronous XHR during page dismissal when the page is being navigated away from or closed by the user.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912

so now what to do to make synchronous calls on this event.