# Angular 2 call http before the user close the window

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, application-close

I want to save changes just before the user close the window, but it don't works when I quit the tab.
I'm using router's canDeactivate method and it works when I refresh my page with F5, but when I close the tab datas are not saved. Here is my canDeactivate function in my component :

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    let subject = new Subject<boolean>();
    let observable = subject.asObservable();

    this.service.save(this.data).then(() => {
        subject.next(true);
    });

    return observable.first();
}
```

I already tried this too :

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = false;
    xmlhttp.open("PUT", "http://localhost:8080/rest/api");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(this.data);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `window:beforeunload` is a synchronous event. If you perform an async action within the event listener the event will complete before your async action. That is why your http request is never made.

Unfortunately I could not find any method for forcing Angular 2's HTTP library to be performed synchronously. I was forced to import JQUERY and use AJAX.

```
                // the http call must be synchronous.
                // the 'unload' event won't wait for async
                // angular's http doesn't support synchronous requests
                // this is why we use JQUERY + AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    async: false,
                    url: this.url
                });
```

Comment: Hi, i just tested it in my actual Angular project, and the backend is never reached with this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
handler(event) {
  ...your warning
}
```

See it in action here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload)

Comment: This solution let the user decide if he wants to quit or not, I don't want him to cancel my http call

Comment: There's no option to send an async http call to the server and wait for it before closing the window. You could only inform the user that he's having unsaved changes.

Comment: @MattewEon i am not quite sure if this is possible it's a browser limitation but i searched on SO you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window) . not quite sure if this will help solve the issue

Comment: @cyrix no I can't. I want to save all answers and time spend on a Mcq when the user close the page, to prevent cheating on time.
@ RahulSingh thanks for the link, I already found this post and it's likely what I'm doing..

Comment: The only option would be to try a sync http call via xhr as stated in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39005933/7497763

Comment: I tried with XHR too but it doesn't works. When I close the tab, nothing happen

Comment: I had a "No Accept-content-origin" error like, I fixed it in my Backend. Now there is no errors, but nothing either

Comment: I just added a console.log() on my canDeactivate() function, i can see the log, but the datas are not saved when I close the tab. But they are on refreshing it (btw I added the xhr part to my post)

Comment: @MattewEon check if you have the data when you close the browser

Comment: The browser have correct datas, but I put a System.out.println in my backend, the request never reached him when the tab close

Comment: @MattewEon i told you its quite difficult and a browser limitation a work around might be to save in local storage and then do something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150711/discussion-between-mattew-eon-and-rahul-singh).