# on destroy called in angular with browser window closes?

Tags: angular, websocket, lifecycle

An angular 4 app. If I close the browser window, will that call the on destory lifecycle hook? Is there a way to act on the browser close action if not?

Why?

disconnection of web sockets

Comment: got it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window

Answer (score 1):

OnDestroy does NOT react when you close the window. Although you can hook to the browser window event

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
handleBeforeUnload(event) {
    this.unsubscribeFromWhatever();
}
```

This way you can collect garbage from you app