# How to call the API before closing the browser window in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in an Angular 4 application ,In my application I have 5 components 
What I am trying to do is ,When the user close the browser window from any one of  the five components I need to call the API and say the user is closed the window on this time .

In my case the API is not get called when I closed the application.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
        beforeunloadHandler(event) {
            this.WindowClosed();
        }

        WindowClosed() {

            this.CartdataService.get_DummyCall().subscribe();
        }
}
```

Here I haven't implemented anything other than the above code .
Can anyone tell me Where I did the mistakes.

Reference :

[Angular 2 - Execute code when closing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window/39005933)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it ...

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    public beforeunloadHandler($event) {
    this.CartdataService.get_DummyCall().subscribe();
   }
```

Comment: is there any way to show confirm box before call api?

Comment: This doesnot work for me. I do a call to do splunk log but I cannot see log in database. @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    private beforeunloadHandler($event) {
        this.logHelper.logApplicationClose(this.footerUser, this.footerUserRole, this.clientIPAddress);
    }