# I am trying to open a new Tab to display details of user

Tags: angular

Open a new window tab on click of a button to display details in angular application

I was able to open a new tab with window.open functionality but in order to get the details a web service call is  required i have a component already taking care of that i want to invoke the component on click

```
userHome.html 
   <div id="buttonId">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="detailsWindow()"  
              [ngClass]="UserDetailClass()"    >User Detail</button>
UserHomeComponent
 (click)="detailsWindow(event) {
//routing logic to get to the component i need to invoke UserDetailComponent
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
  }
UserDetailComponent
I will be passing id and Flag as params 
ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetailOnLoad= true;
    this.userId = this.data;
    this.statusFlag = this.data.statusFlag;

    this.userDetailService.getUserDetails( this.userId,this.statusFlag).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.userDetails = data;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a new tab with `window.open`, in wich you can pass a url that match with you `route`, a things like this: `yourComponent/userId`.

In this route you can use a component that take care to show data.

To take the the user's id:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute);

ngOnInit() {
    const params = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userId');
}
```

Comment: In my routing component i have something like this {
    path: 'user-details',
    component:userDetailComponent,
   }

Comment: You must add the parameter to be able to get it in the component `{ path: 'user-details/:userId', component:userDetailComponent, }`

Comment: sure i did added that  how can i invoke that route but  var url ="user-details/1/true";
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');? and in the component how can i get he passed parameters on init()

Comment: @stackdevs I updated with the answer of your question

Comment: @stackdevs accept the answer if you resolve, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Is there a way passing the parameters through data object instead of passing through the url path params? And also i was able to route to a new tab but i want to exclude the app module html in the new tab @Silente13

Comment: Why you should pass data through data object instead url?

Comment: I do not want to pass use id in the url

Comment: @stackdevs so you should create a service that it can take the info of the selected user

Comment: ok got it i will try that  and how do we restrict from opening multiple new tabs ? so on click i was able to open a component to a new tab so i want to limit to that only tab  once we close the active tab then we can open again not while one is already active

Comment: You can set a boolean parameter in `localStorage` to `true` when user enter in the `userDetailComponent`. 
In `ngOnDestroy` you can set the value to `false`, same thing when the user close the tab/window (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window)