# Angular 8 beforeunload event event not work on close tab

Tags: angular

Hey i try to make http request on close tab but its not work,
But if i navigate to other component its work.
I try to change the function like this post [Angular 2 - Execute code when closing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window/39005933#39005933)

But its now work for me.

My http service:

```
  removeCurrentEditor(reportID) {
    return this.http.request('GET', this.baseUrl + this.REPORTS_API + '/' + this.REMOVE_CURRENT_EDITOR
     + '/' + reportID, {responseType: 'json'});
  }
```

my component:

```
 // Handle close tab
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    this.reportService.removeCurrentEditor(this.reportID);
  }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue with our application where we had to issue a http call on close of browser tab. The problem is when the browser is closed, it cancels all xhr calls. Hence there was no way to achieve this and angular does not support syncronous http calls out of the box.

Finally, we ended up using a synchronous xmlhttprequest in the onBeforeUnload event. This way, the browser waits for the call to complete before closing the browser.

```
XMLHttpRequest.open(method, url[, async[, user[, password]]])
```

The async parameter if set to false indicates a synchronous request.

Another option you could explore is something like a heartbeat client which could detect if the application is open. If not, the server could perform the logic.