# update use notifications live with socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

hello i'm trying to use socket io to get user notification from db.
 here is how i'm trying to get data and send them back to user

```
    if(req.user) {
    req.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    setInterval(getNotf,1000)
    function getNotf() {
    User.findOne({email:req.user.email})
    .then(user=>{
        messages=(user.notifications);
        console.log(messages)
                   socket.emit('output', messages);
});
    }  

});
```

}
the problem with that way is that the message sent to all connected users.how can i send them only to the current user?

Answer (score 0):

You can emit the message to the socket having this connection using its Id:

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('output', messages)
```

Within your connection event listener:

```
req.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    setInterval(getNotf,1000)
    function getNotf() {
    User.findOne({email:req.user.email})
    .then(user=>{
        messages=(user.notifications);
        console.log(messages)
                   io.to(socket.id).emit('output', messages)
});
```

I am have a global instance for the connection like this:

```
var serverhttp = http.createServer(<optionshttp>, app).listen(<port>);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serverhttp);
```

As a test with 2 connections you can try this:

```
        var clients = [];

            req.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 
                clients.push(socket.id);
                setInterval(getNotf,1000)
                function getNotf() {
                User.findOne({email:req.user.email})
                .then(user=>{
                    messages=(user.notifications);
                    console.log(messages)
                    console.log("socket ID :",socket.id)
                    io.to(clients[0]).emit('output', "user1")
                    io.to(clients[1]).emit('output', "user2")
    //or
    //io.sockets.connected[clients[0]].emit('output', "user1") 
    //io.sockets.connected[clients[1]].emit('output', "user2") 

            });
```

Comment: i tried that also, but if user is connected the message sent also to the other  connections

Comment: Can you try to log socket.id for your connections, console.log("socket ID :",socket.id). and tell me please how you test this use case of multiple connections ?

Comment: here is the code on client 
     var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on("output", data => {
        $("#temp").text(data.length)
        console.log(data)
    }
is right?

Comment: I will ask you to do this as a test.

in the client:

var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:<port>") it is with http://

from the server:

io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('output', messages)

and please tell me your socekt.io version from your package.json file and log the socket.id after on connection event from the server as i asked you

Comment: can you try the test part in what i edited in my answer and tell me what you got

Comment: I'm using version 2.04
i'm getting this error 
an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L_4qk9D'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: if i remove the parameters in io.connect on client side the console output is
socket ID : 0shyb48hfV68p980AAAB
socket ID : Lv_PtP7LcJNqUQcKAAAC

Comment: for the security error you can do this: var socket = io.connect("localhost:<port>",{rejectUnauthorized: false}) but anyway i think you can remove it as you have done (Y)

Comment: There are actually to 2 different socket with 2 different Ids so  you should be able to differentiate for whom you would like to send the message. Did you try the test part ?

Comment: yes i tried the test, didn't help.but when i user disconnect i get error  Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Comment: should i store the socket id to the user db and then emit the message to only this one?

Comment: For this error close the connection for this socket:

    .io.sockets.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('DIsconnected!!! ');
io.sockets.disconnect();
io.sockets.close();
        });

Comment: This a good link to handle disconnect event:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287330/socket-io-handling-disconnect-event

Comment: For storing the socket ID in a persistent way(DB) no, because this user wouldn't always have this socket connection for ever and his socket id will change but in an array yes(RAM) and you can use a map instead of an array , in order to have for example the key is the userID and his socketID and you will need to manage when this map also on disconnect

Comment: I forget this in the past comment"for example the key is the userID and  his socketID *as the value*"