# How to track number of active connections to page per user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I want to track the number of connection a specific user makes using mongodb and node.js but I can't find the right way to do it

I have a database of users, each user has a document with a set limitation of how many pages open at the same time he can have but I can't track it.
I tried using Socket.io but I couldn't find a way to assign different connections from different devices to the same account.

(I simplified the function, I don't actually save the code like this)

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.activationCode == '123') {
        return User.findOne({
            activationCode: '123'
        }, function (err, doc) {
            doc.active_users++;
            doc.save();
        }).then(docs => {
            res.render('index', {
                settings: docs.settings
            })
        })
    }
    res.render('login')
});
```

And I also have this code

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please explain how your code currently functions (i.e. what exactly isn't working).

Comment: In this code I increase the number of active users every time a user access the page but I don't know how to know when to decrease this number...

Comment: You can track socket connection and disconnection on the server side, which will be the most reliable method. Take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287330/socket-io-handling-disconnect-event